# Checking certificate validity using HttpClientCertificate vs. X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ssl, security

My IIS (web server) requires client certificate and I need to check for certificate validity and read some information from and record in database (Audit)

I have following code

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

...

HttpClientCertificate cert = Request.ClientCertificate;    
if (cert.IsPresent && cert.IsValid) {
    X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(cert.Certificate);
    bool verified = cer.Verify();
    ...
    AuditLog( ... );
}
```

`cert.IsValid` shows that certificate is valid. Do I need to instantiate X509Certificate2 object and re-check the validity of certificate (Why)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the certificate wasn't valid you wouldn't get this far. IIS should check that during the handshake, and abort the connection if invalid. All you need to do is verify that the identity represented by the Subject DN is authorized to be a client of this application.